# Windows firewall continues to log a dropped multicast packet, even though the rule matches on port

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-firewall, multicast

I have two executables that communicate via UDP multicast sockets on separate Windows machines connected via a hub.  Machine 192.168.1.40 is not receiving the messages from 192.168.1.41. I have configured an incoming rule for port 11017 on the .40 machine, but it still doesn't seem to be allowing the connection.

On the .40 machine, I've enabled logging and find these messages periodically logged: 
2015-08-10 15:07:25 DROP UDP 192.168.1.41 224.144.1.0 12044 11017 104 - - - - - - - RECEIVE

A "netsh advfirewall firewall show rule RuleName" on the .40 machine gives:

### Rule Name:                                   RuleName

Enabled:                                     Yes 
Direction:                                   In 
Profiles:                                    Domain,Private,Public 
Grouping:                                     
LocalIP:                                     Any 
RemoteIP:                                    Any 
Protocol:                                    UDP 
LocalPort:                                   11017 
RemotePort:                                  Any 
Edge traversal:                              No 
Action:                                      Allow 
Ok.

and a "netsh firewall show state" on the .40 machine confirms that it is listening on port 11017 for UDP, any version, null program.

I've turned the firewall off/on after adding the rule and disabled my anti-virus, but it still appears to be logging any traffic to that port as dropped in the firewall log.  Do I need to do something special since it's multicast messages?